# How to automatically set the axes with the plot? sns.kdeplot

Tags: python, seaborn, axis

I have not been able to configure the plot image with the field drawing.
The data provider uses the measures x = 105 and y = 68.

Even in this picture you can see that the goals are out of bounds.

```py
matplotsoccer.field('white',figsize=10, show=False)
    
#Tidy Axes
plt.axis('Off')
   
    sns.kdeplot(df_acciones_ataque["x"],df_acciones_ataque["y"],n_levels=50, shade="True",cmap = 'coolwarm')
    
plt.ylim(0, 68)
plt.xlim(0,105)
    
#plt.suptitle("Acciones de Contraataques y Ataque Elaborado", fontsize=12)
plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)
#plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
    
    
#Display Pitch
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please provide Minimal, [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so anyone can help you better.

Comment: What is `df_acciones_ataque["x"].max()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 2D kdeplot, Seaborn chooses the limits from the given data points. In the latest version (now 0.11.1), you can set a threshold (`thres=`) to prevent the lowest layer to be plotted. Setting `thres=0` will draw all layers; the best value depends on the data and what you want to show. In older versions, one could use `shade_lowest=False`.

Apart, there is `clim` which limits the area (but can not make it larger). To have the image nicely filled to the desired area, one could use both `clim` and explicitly add a rectangle with the color of the lowest level:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(1234)
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(18, 5))
for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3):
    ax.plot([0, 0, 105, 105, 0], [0, 68, 68, 0, 0], color='black')
    ax.plot([105 / 2, 105 / 2], [0, 68], color='black')
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((105 / 2, 68 / 2), 9.15, fc='none', ec='black'))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
    sns.kdeplot(x=np.random.normal(105 / 2, 12, 200), y=np.random.normal(68 / 2, 8, 200), n_levels=50,
                shade="True", cmap=cmap, clip=((0, 105), (0, 68)), thresh=0 if ax == ax1 else 0.002, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlim(-2, 107)
    ax.set_ylim(-2, 70)
ax1.set_title('drawing the zero level')
ax2.set_title('without drawing the zero level')
ax3.add_patch(Rectangle((0, 0), 105, 68, ec='none', fc=cmap(0), zorder=0))
ax3.set_title('adding a rectangle for the zero level')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]