# How to properly set x/y limits for seaborn.kdeplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiHW6.png)

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
sns.kdeplot(x='est_x',y='est_y',
            data=data_pd.loc[(data_pd.Location=='L2') & (data_pd['Pressing Force (N)']!=0)],
            fill=True, levels=5, color="w", linewidths=1, cmap="rocket", thresh=0, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim((0,5))  #
ax.set_ylim((0,5)  #
plt.show()
```

After I set the `xlim` and `ylim` on the `ax`, the shaded area becomes only existing the area of data points. However, I would like to have the shaded area in the entire square, which is (0,5) to (0,5).

Comment: [How to automatically set the axes with the plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576286/how-to-automatically-set-the-axes-with-the-plot-sns-kdeplot) shows an approach to fill the complete area.

Comment: You can set `cut` to a higher value, though there may be some trial and error to get it to fill out a specific set of axis limits (unless you go through the trouble of working out the exact bandwidth you're using).